# use clusterize.js library with django

Tags: javascript, django, clusterize

Hi I'm trying to test using clusterize.js with my django app, the hope is to use it to load large tables with hundreds of rows of data on my html page. I am loading this html file in a view as an httpResponse:

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">

<head>
    <link rel='icon' href="{% static 'images/icon.png' %}" type='image/x-icon' />
    <link href="{% static 'clusterize/clusterize.css' %}">
    <link href="{% static 'clusterize/clusterize.min.js' %}">
    <!--
  <link href="./clusterize.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="./clusterize.min.js"></script>
  -->

    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="description" content="popularify">
    <meta name="author" content="martinbarker">

    <title>popularify</title>

</head>

<body>
    <div>test</div>
    <button onclick="myFunction()">Call myFunction()</button>
    <div id="scrollArea" class="clusterize-scroll">
        <div id="contentArea" class="clusterize-content">
            <div class="clusterize-no-data">Loading data…</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

<script>
    async function myFunction() {
        console.log("myFunction()")
        var data = ['<div>1…</div>', '<div>2…</div>', '<div>3</div>'];
        var clusterize = new Clusterize({ rows: data, scrollId: 'scrollArea',contentId: 'contentArea' });
    }


</script>
```

My static files load fine, and there are no initial errors in console when I load the page, but when I click the button, which calls the js function, i get the error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: Clusterize is not defined
```

Pointing to the line:

```
var clusterize = new Clusterize({ rows: data, scrollId: 'scrollArea',contentId: 'contentArea' });
```

If I am trying to load clusterize.js using on the source files, instead of as an npm package or anything, do I need to tell my html page that the static js file I load should be referenced when creating the new Clusterize var?